# What does the third parameter of text-shadow (blur-radius) do?

Tags: css

As the title says, what does blur-radius do?

According to [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-shadow/)

> The third value, the blur radius, is an optional value which can be specified but don’t have to. It’s the amount of pixels the text is stretched which causes a blur effect. If you don’t use the third value it is treated as if you specified a blur radius of zero.

What does it mean by "the amount of pixels the text is stretched?"

If I set text-shadow like this on an element

```
text-shadow: 0px 0px red;
```

the shadow will not be visible.

But if I set a bigger blur-radius, like this

```
text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px red;
```

the shadow will become visible.

I want to understand why does it happen.

Yes, the blur becomes bigger because the blur radius has a higher value - but how does it work? The value of "2px" will mean that the blur will spread over 2px? **If blur-radius is set to 0, does that mean that the shadow of the text is as big as the letters?**

Can anybody explain to me how does this "blur-radius" work?

Comment: your answer is here @john Smith https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/box-shadow/#:~:text=The%20blur%20radius%20(required)%2C,be%2010px%20of%20total%20shadow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, look at the example of `box-shadow`:

```css
.box {
  float: left;
  padding: 2em;
  margin: 2em;
  background: #f5f5f5
}

/* Move shadow a bit */
.box-1 { box-shadow: 0 20px 0 #ddd }
.box-2 { box-shadow: 0 20px 10px #ddd }
.box-3 { box-shadow: 0 20px 20px #ddd }
.box-4 { box-shadow: 0 20px 50px #ddd }
```

```html
<div class="box box-1">0px</div>
<div class="box box-2">10px</div>
<div class="box box-3">20px</div>
<div class="box box-4">50px</div>
```

The same will be with `text-shadow` blur - but the shadow is in the form of text.

You could see, what if the blur radius is set to `0`, the shadow is the same size as the element. Because of it, the shadow in this case is invisible.

An example with `text-shadow`:

```css
.box {
  float: left;
  padding: 2em;
  margin: 2em;
}

/* Move shadow a bit */
.box-1 { text-shadow: 0 20px 0 red }
.box-2 { text-shadow: 0 20px 10px red }
.box-3 { text-shadow: 0 20px 20px red }
.box-4 { text-shadow: 0 20px 50px red }
```

```html
<div class="box box-1">0px</div>
<div class="box box-2">10px</div>
<div class="box box-3">20px</div>
<div class="box box-4">50px</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

because the shadow is just beneath the element and you didn't provide any axis distance.
Well let me simplify it.

```
text-shadow: 2px 1px red;
```

Here 2px is basically you're saying that move the shadow 2px at x-axis. On the other hand 1px is simply saying move the shadow 1px at y-axis. So if you assign them 0px it'll simply not move anywhere and will be beneath the element. While blur is to blur out the shadow
.
I recommend you to view documentation to understand CSS property. W3school is best refer here
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-shadow.asp

Comment: Thanks for your answer. "it'll simply not move anywhere and will be beneath the element" solved it for me.

Answer (score -1):

You can control the blur with first and second parameter. As example, you can browse the image below

[Text Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92lnb.png)